# Implicit equation. Can it be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Is it possible to find a function $x:[0,T]\to [0,x_0]$ such that, for a fixed $0<\lambda<1$ we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{1+\lambda}\left (1-\dfrac{x(t)}{x_0}\right )^{1+\lambda} +\dfrac{1}{1-\lambda} \left (1-\dfrac{x(t)}{x_0}\right )^{1-\lambda}=\dfrac{2}{1-\lambda^2}-\dfrac{2v_P t}{x_0},\ \forall t\in I$$

At least, there is such a function? Is it unique?

This equation gives a pursuit curve. See Bouguer Problem, on Chases and Escapes: The Mathematics of Pursuit and Evasion by Paul Nahin, page 7.

Comment: If $t=T$ then you get $\frac 1 {1-\lambda ^2} = \frac {v_P T} {x_0}$, so no, in general you can't, not unless the parameters involved satisfy this relation.

Comment: Need $x(T)$ be $x_0$?

Comment: It can be. But then $T=\frac{x_0}{v_P (1-\lambda^2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $t=T$ your equation gives $\frac 1 {1-\lambda^2} = \frac {v_P T} {x_0}$. If this is not satisfied, there can be no solution as you wish. Let us call this condition "the existence condition".

Consider the function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$, $f(y) = \frac 1 {1-\lambda} y^{1-\lambda} + \frac 1 {1+\lambda} y^{1+\lambda}$. Note that $f$ is derivable and $f'(y) = y^{-\lambda} + y^{\lambda} >0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing, therefore its range will be $[0, \frac 2 {1-\lambda ^2}]$, and $f$ will admit an inverse $g:[0, \frac 2 {1-\lambda ^2}] \to [0,1]$. Since $f'$ is continuously derivable and $f'(y) \ne 0 \space \forall y \in [0,1]$, by the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), $g$ will also be continuously derivable.

Your equation can be rewritten as $f(1 - \frac {x(t)} {x_0}) = \frac 2 {1-\lambda ^2} - \frac {2 v_P t} {x_0}$. Since the existence condition is satisfied, the left-hand side is in $[0, \frac 2 {1-\lambda^2}]$ and we can apply $g$, so $1 - \frac {x(t)} {x_0} = g(\frac {2 v_P t} {x_0})$, which means that $x(t) = x_0 - x_0 g(\frac 2 {1-\lambda ^2} - \frac {2 v_P t} {x_0})$. Note that $x(0) = 0$ and, thanks to the existence condition, $x(T) = x_0$. Furthermore, since $g$ is continuously derivable, so will be $x$.

We can conclude that the existence condition is necessary and sufficient for your question to be answered in the affirmative.